# Show that for any $n∈\Bbb N$, numbers $x_n$ and $y_n$ are nonzero.

Tags: matrices

Matrix $A=$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and
$A^n$ is of the form $A^n = $$\begin{pmatrix} x_n & -2y_n \\ y_n & x_n\end{pmatrix}$

Where i arrived at:
$\det(A) = 3 \implies \det(A^n)=3^n$, so if $x_n$ and $y_n$ are both zero, then $\det(A^n)=0$, and that is a contradiction, because $3^n\neq 0, \forall n \in \Bbb N$.
If $x_n=0 \implies \det(A^n) = 2y_n$, which is a contradiction, because $3^n$ can't be even.

What i need is a way to solve the case of $y_n=0$.

Comment: Hello, it's probably better to compute a few cases, guess the formula for $x_n$ and $y_n$, and then prove the statement by induction. Or just prove the formula by induction. All you have to prove is that each power $A^n$ has a constant diagonal and that the off diagonal elements satisfy the same linear equation.

Comment: HAve you heard about eigenvalues and eigenvbectors? Can you show some context/background in order to use adequate tools?

Comment: I'm in highschool 12th grade, i have never heard of eigenvalues

Comment: I can't see any straightforward way of proving that $y_n$ isn't 0. (I might be wrong of course!). I started sketching out an induction proof, which requires some additional assumptions, such as $x_n\not= y_n$ and $x_n \not= -\frac{1}{2}y_n$. I am wondering if the intention of the exercise is just to show that both of them are not 0, as you did, and not to prove it separately. The 'and' in mathematics usually means when both are true. The 'or' is inclusive and can mean either or both, so if it was to show '$x_n$ or $y_n$ are nonzero', you would be required to prove it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a companion to Will Jagy's answer.

It is straightforward to verify that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\-1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_n&-2y_n\\y_n&x_n
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{n+1}&-2y_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}&x_{n+1}\tag1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by setting
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=x_n+2y_n\tag{2a}\\
y_{n+1}&=y_n-x_n\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Using $\overbrace{x_n=y_n-y_{n+1}}^{\text{from (2b)}}$ in $\text{(2a)}$, we get
$$
\overbrace{y_{n+1}-y_{n+2}}^{x_{n+1}}=\overbrace{y_n-y_{n+1}}^{x_n}+2y_n\implies y_{n+2}=2y_{n+1}-3y_n\tag{3a}
$$
and using $\overbrace{y_n=\frac12(x_{n+1}-x_n)}^{\text{from (2a)}}$ in $\text{(2b)}$, we get
$$
\overbrace{\tfrac12(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1})}^{y_{n+1}}=\overbrace{\tfrac12(x_{n+1}-x_n)}^{y_n}-x_n\implies x_{n+2}=2x_{n+1}-3x_n\tag{3b}
$$
Therefore, $\text{(3a)}$ and $\text{(3b)}$ become
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&\equiv-x_n\pmod3\tag{4a}\\
y_{n+1}&\equiv-y_n\pmod3\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
and since $x_1=1$ and $y_1=-1$, $(4)$ guarantees that $x_n\ne0$ and $y_n\ne0$ for $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 6):

the $x,y$ are always integers. Then

$x_n$ follows a recurrence
$$ x_{n+2} = 2 x_{n+1} - 3 x_n  $$
beginning with
$$  1, -1, -5, -7, 1, 23, 43, \ldots$$

Next, $y_n$ follows a recurrence
$$ y_{n+2} = 2 y_{n+1} - 3 y_n  $$
beginning with
$$  -1, -2, -1, 4, 11, 10, -13, \ldots$$

Neither one is ever divisible by $3$ so cannot be zero.

Comment: Can this formula be proven?

Comment: @VeryNice: the recurrences mod $3$ are $x_n=-x_{n-1}$ and $y_n=-y_{n-1}$

Comment: @robjohn the recurrences are Cayley-Hamilton for the matrix. They can also be found just writing out things for the $n+2$ and $n+1$  recipes for $x,y$  and solving; this is, of course, the proof of Cayley-Hamilton in dimension 2

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in a reformulation of your result.
For $n\ge 0,$
$$x_n =\Re (1+i\sqrt 2)^n$$
$$y_n =-{1\over\sqrt 2}\Im (1+i\sqrt 2)^n$$
Thus, you've shown that $\tan^{-1}{\sqrt 2}$ is not a rational number times $\pi.$

Comment: (+1) Indeed: $x^2-2x+3=0$ has roots $x=1\pm i\sqrt2$. I like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, this is an inessential companion to Will and robjohn's answers.
It took me a while to see a state space relationship.

With $z_k=(x_{k+1},y_{k+1},x_k,y_k)$ we have $z_{k+1}=B_1 z_k$, where
$B_1=\begin{bmatrix} A& 0 \\ 0 & A\end{bmatrix}$. However, we also have the constraint $z_0 \in \ker \begin{bmatrix} I & -A\end{bmatrix} = {\cal R} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ I\end{bmatrix}$, and we see that the subsequent trajectory lies in this subspace as well. Hence we can modify $B_1$ in any way as long as the subspace lies in the kernel of the modification.

Will's recurrent satisfies $z_{k+1}=B_2 z_k$, where
$B_2=\begin{bmatrix} 2I& -3I \\ I & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and it is straightforward to check that $(B_1-B_2) \begin{bmatrix} A \\ I\end{bmatrix} = 0$ (note that $A$ satisfies $A^2-2A+3I = 0$).